# Smart card authentication using LDAP

Tags: java, c++, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to design an authentication system. The system will use ActivClient in order to communicate with a smart card.

The ActivClient exposes an API which allows me to read the card's certificate, and to sign a random message using it's private key.

I have a client - server architecture.

Is there a way to use the LDAP to manage the authentication, or I have to implement it by myself (read the cert from the card, give the card challenge, send this values to the server, check the CA and check if the user is known by the LDAP)?

Thanks,

Mattan